# find data that's not in both tables across different MySQL servers

Tags: php, mysql

I'm searching for a way to compare two tables, and determine which rows are missing in one table. These two tables are on different MySQL servers.

```
Table 1
----------------
Apple
Microsoft
Google

Table 2 
----------
Apple
Google
```

What I want is to show a list of the items from Table 1 that are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to get the outcome you want, if you want to use PHP it is easiest like so:

```
$table1 = mysql_query("SELECT fieldname.....");
$table2 = mysql_query("SELECT fieldname.....");

$results_table2 = mysql_fetch_array($table2);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($table2))
  {

  if(!in_array($row['fieldname'], $results_table2))
    {

    echo $row['fieldname'] ." not in both tables";

  }

}
```

Maybe even work with `array_intersect` instead of a while loop.

```
$table1 = mysql_query("SELECT fieldname.....");
$table2 = mysql_query("SELECT fieldname.....");

$results_table1 = mysql_fetch_array($table1, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$results_table2 = mysql_fetch_array($table2, MYSQL_ASSOC);

$result1 = array_intersect($results_table1, $results_table2);
print_r($result1);

$result2 = array_diff($results_table1, $results_table2);
print_r($result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should select all of the data from table 1 and place them in a array-table1 and do the same with table 2 but for table2 place them in array-table2. after that then compare the two arrays and display the data which is not in array-table1 or in array-table2. I hope it will help.